# Show subset $W$ is a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

The question asks "Show that a subset $W$ of a vector space is a subspace if and only if $\mathrm{Span}(W) = W$"

How would you go about solving this proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we know what is exactly span of a set. Let $A$ be any set. Then the span of $A$ is defined as the set of all possible linear combinations of elements of $A$. This definition is the formal one.

To see this definition more closely:

Let $A=\{x\}$. Now the question is $\textbf{what is the intersection of all the subspaces containng $x$ ?}$.

Let us denote the subspaces containg $x$ by $M_1,M_2,\cdots$.

We know that the intersection of any collection of subspaces is again a subspace, so $\cap M_i$ is a subspace containg $x$.

What is the shape of $\cap M_i$?

Since $x \in \cap M_i$ and $\cap M_i$ is a subspace, so it must contains all the scalar mutiples of $x$ .

Consequently, $\{\alpha x: \alpha \in F\} \subseteq \cap M_i$

On the other hand, one can prove $\cap M_i \subseteq \{\alpha x: \alpha \in F\}$

Finally, $\cap M_i = \{\alpha x: \alpha \in F\}=\textbf{span\{x\}}$, which is a subspace.

In general, take $A$ be any set and one can prove $\textbf{span(A) is the intersection of all the subspaces containg $A$}$.

$\textbf{Added:}$

The word "Span" is like a set theoretic operation, because $\textbf{it converts a set into a subspace}$

The three basic fact about span are:

1) span operation is monotone

$$ A \subseteq B \implies span(A) \subseteq span(B)$$

2) span operation is increasing

$$ A \subseteq span(A)$$ for any set $A$

3) span operation is idempotent

$$ span(span(A))=span(A)$$

The answer for your question is follows from these facts!

$\textbf{Reference}:$

Linear algebra problem book by P.R.Halmos

Answer (score 1):

It is always true that $W\subset\operatorname{span}(W)$. And it is always true that $\operatorname{span}(W)$ is a vector subspace of $V$. Therefore, if $W=\operatorname{span}(W)$, then $W$ is a vector subspace of $V$. On the other hand, if $W$ is a vector subspace of $V$, then, since $\operatorname{span}(W)$ is the smallest vector subspace of $V$ containing $W$, $\operatorname{span}(W)=W$.